# how to print same rows values of different columns in a excel file using python

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, exception

i have an excel file that after each FOR loop adds one "SN" column to excel find.
**what i want is** to find the same rows in different "SN" columns.
THIS IS THE EXCEL THAT I WANT TO DO OPERATION ON :

```
print (df)
   SN1   R1   SN2    R2
0  SN1   38  SN20  1000
1  SN2   38  SN21   181
2  SN3  532  SN23     5
3  SN4  521  SN25    38
4  SN6  115  SN26  8718
5  SN7    3  SN27  3452
6  SN8  136  SN28   229
7  SN9  168  SN30   136
```

**AND THIS IS THE RESULT THAT I WANT**
[image]

THE CODES :

```
v=int(input("how many periods do you have:\n"))
new_excel_by_user=str(input("write the name of your new EXCEL 
file:"))
user_excel = pd.ExcelWriter(new_excel_by_user+'.xlsx', 
engine='xlsxwriter')
sys_excel=pd.ExcelWriter('sys_excel132.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
final_excel=pd.ExcelWriter('final132.xlsx' , engine='xlsxwriter')


merged_df_H = pd.DataFrame()
merged_df_L = pd.DataFrame()
final_merged=pd.DataFrame()


for i in range(v):
print("\npriod %d :"%(i+1))

excelpathH=''+input(''+r"Insert your Excel path(HIGH):")
excelpathL=''+input(''+r"Insert your Excel path(LOW):")
excelpathH=excelpathH.replace('"', '')
excelpathL=excelpathL.replace('"', '')
dfH=pd.read_excel(os.path.join(excelpathH), engine='openpyxl' )
dfL=pd.read_excel(os.path.join(excelpathL), engine='openpyxl' )

Rnh=dfH['KPIVALUE']
Rnl=dfL['KPIVALUE']
R=Rnh-Rnl
merged_df_H['R%s'%(i+1)]=R
R=merged_df_H['R%s'%(i+1)]
#the below code returns true false only
RESULT=merged_df_H['R%s'%(i+1)].ge(130)
merged_df_H = 
pd.concat([merged_df_H,dfH.loc[mask,'SN'].rename('SN%s'% 
(i+1)).reset_index(drop=True),
R[mask].reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)


merged_df_H = pd.concat([ merged_df_H,dfH,dfL,R,RESULT], axis=1 )

final_merged=pd.concat([final_merged,dfH['SN'], R,RESULT],axis=1)
```

**BAD RESULT:**
[image]

new**strong text**
[image]

Comment: Please fix your code indentation so that it will work copy/pasting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) for get `SN` and `R` columns, reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and filter same values by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
R = df.filter(like='R').stack().reset_index(drop=True)
SN = df.filter(like='SN').stack().reset_index(drop=True)
mask = R.duplicated(keep=False)

print (pd.concat([SN[mask], R[mask]], axis=1, keys=('SN-RESULT','R-RESULT')))
   SN-RESULT  R-RESULT
0        SN1        38
2        SN2        38
7       SN25        38
12       SN8       136
15      SN30       136

out = df.join(pd.concat([SN[mask], R[mask]], 
                        axis=1, 
                        keys=('SN-RESULT','R-RESULT')).reset_index(drop=True))
```

If columns `SN-RESULT, R-RESULT` are already in input DataFrame add `rsuffix` to [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
out = df.join(pd.concat([SN[mask], R[mask]], 
                        axis=1, 
                        keys=('SN-RESULT','R-RESULT')).reset_index(drop=True), 
              rsuffix='_new')
```

Another idea with [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html)`:

```
R = df.filter(like='R').melt()['value']
SN = df.filter(like='SN').melt()['value']
mask = R.duplicated(keep=False)
out = df.join(pd.concat([SN[mask], R[mask]], 
                       axis=1, 
                       keys=('SN-RESULT','R-RESULT')).reset_index(drop=True))
```

Comment: IT GIVES ME THIS ERROR

Comment: ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['SN-RESULT', 'R-RESULT'], dtype='object')

Comment: @SOURAELLE - So this columns (`['SN-RESULT', 'R-RESULT']`) are already in `DataFrame` ?

Comment: no they are not, they must be added when the values in "SN" columns are same .

Comment: @SOURAELLE - Added `print (pd.concat([SN[mask], R[mask]], axis=1, keys=('SN-RESULT','R-RESULT')))` for check if correct output, and in second paragraph solution for avoid `ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified`

Comment: I ADDED ONE IMAGE AS BAD RESULT. WHEN I RUN THE NEW CODES, THE OUTPUT OF MY EXCEL WAS LIKE THAT IMAGE

Comment: @SOURAELLE - bad result is from `print (pd.concat([SN[mask], R[mask]], axis=1, keys=('SN-RESULT','R-RESULT')))` ?

Comment: NO, IT IS FROM HERE:                  ------->>>>

Comment: mask = merged_df_H['R%s'%(i+1)].ge(140)

   R = merged_df_H.filter(like='R').stack().reset_index(drop=True)
   SN = merged_df_H.filter(like='SN').stack().reset_index(drop=True)
   mask = R.duplicated(keep=False)
 
   merged_df_H = pd.concat([merged_df_H,SN[mask], R[mask],
                         dfH.loc[mask,'SN'].rename('SN%s'%(i+1)).reset_index(drop=True),
                         R[mask].reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)

Comment: @SOURAELLE - I see. You need add my solution after loop,my  `df` is for you `final_merged` after finish looping.

Comment: @SOURAELLE Do you know typing in upper case is `SHOUTING` ???

Comment: no , it has nothing to "final_merged", even the out put is not the way i desire

Comment: for example, number 136 is in both SN8 and SN30

Comment: @Goku , thank you for warning

Comment: @jezrael i fixed the problem and also tried another task. this code that you helped me to solve gives the "out", based on "R"s, but what if i eant to have an putput based on "SN"s???? i maean i wanrt an out put where "SN" are duplicated in all of the "SN" columns?

Comment: i did a try, but raised an error : pandas.errors.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).

Comment: @SOURAELLE - change `mask = R.duplicated(keep=False)` to `mask = SN.duplicated(keep=False)`

Comment: i did, but gives me an error such as above

Comment: @SOURAELLE - If testing solution with melt also failed?

Comment: i did not try, i am going to make a try, and  will let you know

Comment: @jezrael  i tried with "melt" but this line of the code give an error :                out = merged_df_H.join(pd.concat([SN[mask], R[mask]],

Comment: @SOURAELLE - So it means, there are some `R`, `SN` pairs columns missing, eg are columns `R1,R2,R3` and `SN1, SN2` only

Comment: @jezrael would you pleade explain it more?

Comment: @SOURAELLE - Check `print (df.columns)` - are there all pairs with same number `R` and `SN` columns? It means if columns are `[R1,R2,R3, SN1, SN2]` there missing pair for `R3` because no `SN3`. It is reason for error

Comment: @jezrael really really thank you, you helped and i solve the problem, can i ask one more question?

Comment: @SOURAELLE - yop,

Comment: for some of my excel files i get this error, what does it mean? :                Exception has occurred: AssertionError
exception: no description

Comment: @SOURAELLE - Hard question, I can guess - missing column e.g. `R` or `SN` ? empty file? You need identify this file and there have to be something wrong.

Comment: error occurs in this line:           merged_df_H= pd.concat([merged_df_H,
                         dfH.loc[mask, 'CellName'].reset_index(drop=True),

Comment: @jezrael i myself guess one point : if have any empty rows in my excel, can it cause any problem?

Comment: @SOURAELLE - If use `stack` and empty rows should help not remove it by `stack(dropna=False)`

Comment: what does it mean?

Comment: @SOURAELLE - empty rows create missing values and `stack()` remove it. If use `stack(dropna=False)` it not remove it.

Comment: how does the code would it be?

Comment: change `stack` to `stack(dropna=False)` twice

Comment: @jezrael but i dont have any "stack" word, in my code

Comment: @SOURAELLE - First ans second line of code.

Comment: @jezrael the last question : i run the code and the output is correct but as i told befor , for example , SN28 is in all of the columns and i must have SN28 as output, but it prints SN28 as columns times, if i have two SN column , it shows SN28 two times, but.... i just want to be added just once in the ne column "SN-RESULT"

Comment: @SOURAELLE - So need all duplicates by `R` columns and then remove duplicates by `SN` ? Not sure if understand.

Comment: i have duplicated "SN"s and also "R"s. because by every "SN", one "R" creates.  so i have both duplicated SN and R.  i added image by title: new

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255863/discussion-between-jezrael-and-soura-elle).